# Обьединение двух пересекающих запросов (SQL)

Tags: sql

Дорогие программисты,
У меня есть 2 простых запроса.
<Br>Первый запрос:

```
TRANSFORM Count(index.[Код]) AS [Count-Код]
SELECT index.[SudName], Count(index.[Код]) AS [Sum]
FROM [index]
GROUP BY index.[SudName]
PIVOT index.[NotEnter] IN ("Error No2", "Error No3", "Error No4");
```

Второй запрос:

```
TRANSFORM Count(index.Код) AS [Count-Код]
SELECT index.SudName, Count(index.Код) AS [Sum]
FROM [index]
GROUP BY index.SudName
PIVOT index.Result IN("Opened","Closed","Deleted","ReOpened");
```

Как я могу обьединить их самым простым способом, чтобы моя таблица выглядела так, как на [рисунке](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualfile.aspx?id=12580885) (или без сумм. В крайнем случае, я сам могу заполучить сумму в отчете).

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу быть уверен, что это сработает, но можно попробовать CTE:

```
WITH Table1 as (
TRANSFORM Count(index.[Код]) AS [Count-Код]
SELECT index.[SudName], Count(index.[Код]) AS [Sum]
FROM [index]
GROUP BY index.[SudName]
PIVOT index.[NotEnter] IN ("Error No2", "Error No3", "Error No4"))
, Table2 as (
TRANSFORM Count(index.Код) AS [Count-Код]
SELECT index.SudName, Count(index.Код) AS [Sum]
FROM [index]
GROUP BY index.SudName
PIVOT index.Result IN("Opened","Closed","Deleted","ReOpened"))
select Table2.*, Table1.*
from Table1
     inner join Table2
             on Table1.SudName = Table2.SudName
```